# Erroneous redirect behaviour

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I'm stuck with a problem as I can't find the reason causing such a behaviour.

The problem in short:
I have a site. When I go to http://mysite.com - loads fine. The url doesn't change.
When I go to http://www.mysite.com - redirects to http://mysite.com/index.php/

Initially I had some rules in .htaccess, but now - I commented all of them, so the behaviour is reproduced with clean .htaccess.

In config of codeigniter I have:

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://mysite.com/";
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

I checked the apache config - didn't find any redirects that could behave like this.

Any thoughts where to dig?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was pretty stupid from my side - but just put it here, maybe for someone else that would help not to spend too much time as I did.

The problem was that I worked with local version of site, and recently has changed the hosts file. Now there was 127.0.0.1 written only for main domain, but not for subdomains.

So basically when I entered www.site.com I downloaded from the production version of site.
Really stupid mistake.